# SQL multiple columns grouping in one row

Tags: sql, sql-server, grouping

I have the following table in SQL

```
AL1 | AL2 | AL3 | ACB | LL1 | LL2 | LL3 | LCB  
------------------------------------------------
 1  |  2  |  3  |  4  |  5  |  6  |  7  |  8
```

I would like to convert it as

```
    | L1  | L2  | L3  | CB  
-----------------------------
A   |  1  |  2  |  3  |  4   
L   |  5  |  6  |  7  |  8
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide more information. At least we need to know which database server do you use and how the table look like?

Comment: I am using MS SQL server. The first code snippet represents the table - AL1,...,LCB are all the columns. The table has 1 row with the corresponding values - 1,...,8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can select both with different query and join them using `UNION`

```
SELECT 'A' AS COL, AL1, AL2, AL3, ACB
  FROM TBL
 UNION
SELECT 'L' AS COL, LL1, LL2, LL3, LCB
  FROM TBL;
```

Output:

```
| COL | AL1 | AL2 | AL3 | ACB |
-------------------------------
|   A |   1 |   2 |   3 |   4 |
|   L |   5 |   6 |   7 |   8 |
```

#### See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5d7d3/1)

Comment: Nice and easy. Great! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try this one -

***Query:***

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE
(
    AL1 INT, AL2 INT, AL3 INT, ACB INT, 
    LL1 INT, LL2 INT, LL3 INT, LCB INT
)
INSERT INTO @temp (AL1, AL2, AL3, ACB, LL1, LL2, LL3, LCB)
VALUES (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)

SELECT 
      COL
    , COL1 = CASE WHEN COL = 'A' THEN AL1 ELSE LL1 END
    , COL2 = CASE WHEN COL = 'A' THEN AL2 ELSE LL2 END
    , COL3 = CASE WHEN COL = 'A' THEN AL3 ELSE LL3 END
    , COL4 = CASE WHEN COL = 'A' THEN ACB ELSE LCB END
FROM @temp
CROSS JOIN (VALUES ('A'), ('L')) AS t(COL)
```

***Output:***

```
COL  COL1        COL2        COL3        COL4
---- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
A    1           2           3           4
L    5           6           7           8
```

***Execution plan:***

[image: qqq]

Answer (score 3):

Another way (the same plan as Devart's but more concise syntax)

```
SELECT V.*
FROM TBL
CROSS APPLY (VALUES ('A', AL1,AL2,AL3,ACB),
                    ('L', LL1,LL2,LL3,LCB)) V( COL, LL1, LL2, LL3, LCB)
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5d7d3/2)

Comment: +1 But this will work if it is SQL Server 2008+, if they have SQL Server 2005, then you would have to use CROSS APPLY with SELECT/UNION ALL since the VALUES is not available.

Comment: @bluefeet - Yep. And Devart's should work on previous versions if they happen to be on <= 2000. (And replace the `VALUES` with `UNION ALL` again)

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @test AS TABLE(int1 INT, int2 INT, int3 INT, int4 INT)
INSERT INTO @test
    ( int1, int2, int3, int4 )
VALUES  ( 1, -- int1 - int
          2, -- int2 - int
          3, -- int3 - int
          4  -- int4 - int
          )
SELECT * FROM @test

SELECT COL FROM @test
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (int1), (int2), (int3), (int4)) t(COL)
```

Check out this sample.